# is this the correct way to add META TAGS using CakePHP 2.4?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have the default template and a view named home.ctp

When the user call the home page **/** the home **view** is rendered inside default.ctp.

In my *view* I have:

```
<?php

$this->set('title', 'This is the title');

$this->set('description', 'This is the description');

...
?>
```

and in my *default.ctp* I have:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
....

<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
....
```

it works correctly, but, is this the correct way to add title and meta tags in CakePHP ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

### No

That's not a safe way to output your title and description variables.

Cake does have a helper function for [outputting metatags](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#inserting-well-formatted-elements) extract from the docs:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->meta(
    'description',
    'enter any meta description here'
);
?>
// Output
<meta name="description" content="enter any meta description here" />
```

### Alternatively

You don't have to use the above function - but if you don't you must take care to escape your variables. Consider what happens with this:

```
$description = 'something with a "quote in it';
```

if you just blindly echo variables - you're going to create malformed html and/or permit injection attacks. As such it's perfectly fine to use the code in the question if you escape `$title` and `$description` appropriately:

```
<title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?></title>
....
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description); ?>">
```

Comment: Since when do you use htmlspecialchars() instead of h()? :)

Comment: using [h](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/basics.php#L154) would be just another method to lookup - as is the code is obvious to none cakephp users.

Comment: @AD7six I Put the variable in the view, no one can set them... Only me in the .ctp file. However... I can use $this->Html->meta in the layout, but I need to set title and description in the view because each page has different title/description

Comment: Setting view vars in the view is good - e.g. I do it. Not using helper functions is fine. Not escaping all variables unless you need them to not be (already been escaped, contains html) is a bad habit.